# Questions about VaR and CVaR. Is there any relation between $VaR_{\alpha}(X)$ and $VaR_{\alpha}(-X)$, or $CVaR_{\alpha}(X)$ and $CVaR_{\alpha}(-X)$?

Tags: value-at-risk, cvar

I have some questions when dealing with Value-at-Risk (VaR) and Conditional Value-at-Risk (CVaR).

Is there any relationship between $VaR_{\alpha}(X)$ and $VaR_{\alpha}(-
X)$, or $CVaR_{\alpha}(X)$ and $CVaR_{\alpha}(-X)$ ?

Here, $VaR$ and $CVaR$ are defined as:

$$VaR_{\alpha}(X) := \inf \left\{x\in \mathbb{R}| Pr(X >x)\leq \alpha \right\}, \alpha \in [0, 1]$$

$$CVaR_{\alpha}(X) := \frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{0}^{\alpha}VaR_{s}(X)ds$$

Comment: Down-voted, I'd like to know what have you tried? Did you write down the definitions?

Comment: I believe you should improve your question to get a better response.

Comment: So, given those formula's, would you say that there is a relationship?

Comment: Actually, I am not sure. Since $VaR_{\alpha}(-X) = \sup{x \in \mathbb{R}| F_{X}(x) \leq 1-\alpha}$}, I was wondering whether there could be some relation between $VaR_{\alpha}(-X)$ and $VaR_{\alpha}(X)$. It  does not seem apparently.  Maybe some relation holds by applying some trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We consider the case where the distribution function $F$ of $X$ is strictly increasing. Then 
\begin{align*}
VaR_{\alpha}(X) &= \inf\{x: P(X >x) \le \alpha \}\\
&=\inf\{x: F(x)\ge 1-\alpha \}\\
&=F^{-1}(1-\alpha).
\end{align*}
Moreover, we note that the distribution function $G$ of $-X$ is defined by
\begin{align*}
G(x) &= P(-X \le x) \\
&=1-F(-x),
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
VaR_{\alpha}(-X) &= G^{-1}(1-\alpha)\\
&=-F^{-1}(\alpha)\\
&=-VaR_{1-\alpha}(X).
\end{align*}
Furthermore,
\begin{align*}
CVaR_{\alpha}(-X) &=\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_0^{\alpha}VaR_s(-X)ds\\
&=-\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_0^{\alpha}VaR_{1-s}(X)ds\\
&={\color{red}{-}}\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{1-\alpha}^1 VaR_s(X)ds\\
&=-\frac{1}{\alpha}\left(\int_0^1 VaR_s(X)ds - \int_0^{1-\alpha} VaR_s(X)ds\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_0^1F^{-1}(1-s)ds +\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}CVaR_{1-\alpha}(X)\\
&=-\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_0^1F^{-1}(s)ds +\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}CVaR_{1-\alpha}(X)\\
&=-\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\, dF(x) +\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}CVaR_{1-\alpha}(X)\\
&=-\frac{1}{\alpha} E(X) +\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}CVaR_{1-\alpha}(X).
\end{align*}

Comment: Hi Gordon. Thank you again for your help. Your answer is really helpful. But I still doubt about a sign. Could you help me check it ?  
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
CVaR_{\alpha}(-X) &= \frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{0}^{\alpha}VaR_{s}(-X)ds \\
      &= -\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{0}^{\alpha}VaR_{1-s}(X)ds\\
      &= -\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{1}^{1-\alpha}VaR_{t}(X)d(1-t)\\  
      &= -\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{1-\alpha}^{1}VaR_{t}(X)dt)\\
      &= -\frac{1}{\alpha}\left(\int_{1-\alpha}^{0}VaR_{t}(X)dt)+\int_{0}^{1}VaR_{t}(X)dt)\right)\\
     
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: \begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&= -\frac{1}{\alpha}\left(\int_{0}^{1}VaR_{t}(X)dt)-\int_{0}^{1-\alpha}VaR_{t}(X)dt)\right)\\    
      &= -\frac{1}{\alpha}\left(\int_{0}^{1}F^{-1}(1-t)dt - (1-\alpha)CVaR_{1-\alpha}(X)\right)\\
      &= \frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{1}^{0}F^{-1}(s)ds + \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}CVaR_{1-\alpha}(X)\\
      &= -\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{0}^{1}F^{-1}(s)ds + \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}CVaR_{1-\alpha}(X)\\
      &=-\frac{1}{\alpha}E[X] + \frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}CVaR_{1-\alpha}(X).
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: @Xinyuan: Thanks for pointing this out. See the correction.